# An SQL Server 2008 R2 based program fails when updating stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm trying to update [MIP](http://www.abila.com/solutions/abila-mip-fund-accounting) software and one of the "companies" fails while it is updating a stored procedure.

[image: fail updating stored procedures]

Is there any place in SQL Server 2008 R2 / Windows where I could see an error message about what might be causing this?  When I did the installation I gave it the `sa` password, and it worked for all the other "companies" that we have in the system just fine.

Comment: Have you talked to Abila support? They may have information about where they log such errors so you can investigate further. SQL Server doesn't log all errors for you unless they are critical (and this is not). So, you could start a server-side trace or extended events session to see what is really happening behind that dialog, or you could generate the script (if the GUI supports that) and run it yourself in Management Studio.

Comment: I did talk to support; how would I generate the script so I could run it myself?  Would it be somewhere in the installation?

Comment: Sorry, no idea, I have never seen or used that tool, I am just grasping and hope it has an option to generate the script for you instead of only allowing you to run it behind your back.

Comment: Well it sounds like a good idea, I will ask tech support about it.  I feel like I could fix it if I knew what was going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you're running the upgrade, this SQL Server instance must not be in production, right? If so, why don't you fire up the SQL Profiler tool to see what's happening behind the scenes. The trace should show you where the troublesome spot is. Happy troubleshooting! Hope you solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks!  This helped too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199812/logging-erroneous-queries-only-on-sql-server